# Python matrix column cyclic assignment

Tags: python, r

I have a matrix $X=(X_{ij})\in R^{n\times d}$  and a vector $y=(y_i)\in R^{n}$ and I want to centralize $y$ and centralize and normalize $X$ in columns , i.e., $\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i=0$, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ij}=0$ 和 $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{ij}^2=1$, $j=1,2,\ldots,d$.

I have implemented it in R successfully, with  a  toy example  as follows (PS: My toy example is very simple that can be manually computed  and checked! )

```
### wirte the function
normalize = function(X,y){
n = dim(X)[1]; d = dim(X)[2] 
D = matrix(0,d,1)
y = y - mean(y) #center y
for (k in 1:d){
    Xk = X[,k]
    Xk = Xk - mean(Xk) #column-center X
    ck = 1/norm(Xk,"2")
    X[,k] = Xk * ck #column-normalization X
    D[k,1] = ck
}   
out = list(X=X,D=D,y=y)
return(out)
}

### test the function
X = matrix(1:4,2,byrow=T)
y = matrix(1:2) 
out = normalize(X,y)
( ny = out$y ) #show centered y
mean(ny) #check y center
( nX = out$X ) #show centered and normalized X (each column)
apply(nX,2,mean) #check X column-center
apply(nX,2,function(x)norm(x,"2")) #check X column-normalization
```

Then I want to reproduce the R procedure in Python as strictly as possible  and try it as

```py
### wirte the function
import numpy as np
def normalize(X,y):
  n,d = X.shape 
  D = np.zeros((d,1))
  y = y-np.mean(y) #center y
  for k in range(d): 
    Xk = X[:,k]
    Xk = Xk - np.mean(Xk) #column-center X
    ck = 1/np.linalg.norm(Xk)
    X[:,k] = Xk * ck #column-normalization X
    D[k,:] = ck
  
  return X,D,y
 
### test the function
X = np.arange(1,5,1).reshape(2,2)
y = np.array([1,2]).reshape(-1,1)
nX,D,ny = normalize(X,y)
ny #show centered y
np.mean(ny) #check y center
nX #show centered and normalized X (each column)
np.mean(nX,axis=0) #check X column-center
np.linalg.norm(nX, axis=0) #check X column-normalization
```

The results of `ny` and `D` in Python matches that in R.  However, the `nX` output in Python gives obviously the wrong result, which shows the zero matrix!  Did I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you are creating the `X` matrix with `np.arange`, numpy infers the dtype of the matrix to be `int`. Hence, when you are setting the values with `1/sqrt(2)` they get truncated to `0`.

Declare `X` as follows:

```
X = np.arange(1, 5, 1, dtype=np.float64).reshape(2, 2)
```

Resulting `X`:

```
array([[-0.70710678, -0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]])
```

As a side note, you can create a function that returns the same result and does not use a loop by using vectorised numpy functions:

```
def normalize(X, y):
    Xk = X - np.mean(X, axis=0)
    D = 1/np.linalg.norm(Xk, axis=0)
    return Xk * D, D.reshape(-1, 1), y - np.mean(y)
```

Anothet difference is in side-effects. This function does not modify the original `X` matrix, while yours does.

Comment: Yes, your solution is quite elegant and efficient! @user2246849